# run script by calling the parent folder name

Tags: bash

Let's say I create folder named `foo` in `/usr/local/bin` and copy my `bar.sh` script to that folder; `/usr/local/bin/foo/bar.sh`

Is it possible to call `bar.sh` using the `foo` folder name? Like `bar.sh` would execute if named something like `main.sh` or `defautl.sh` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is. If you are not successful, post your best try.

Comment: Well assuming that's the only file you have in that directory and it surely exists, `bash /usr/local/bin/foo/*` would execute it.